# Escape correctly parentheses in EL expression

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Does it exist a way to escape correctly parentheses? I would like to print out the variable  using EL `${(foo)}`. If `foo` is not empty, it should print out `(foo)`

Comment: use `${not empty foo}` to check for not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EL you doesn't need to escape `()`. If you want to print them, then move it outside `${}`.

```
<c:out value="(${foo})"/>
```